# Does using the default ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvier.ChangePassword method alert the PCNS?

Tags: .net, passwords, membership-provider

We've got a Identity Lifecycle Management 2007 Feature Pack 1 server setup that is syncing our student email accounts with live@edu.  We want to allow the students to change their password via the web.  When I use the default "ChangePassword" method inside of the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, it does not trigger the password event that "Password Change Notification Service" which then syncronizes with live@edu.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I'm missing when using this method?  I've gotten as far as to learn that there is a dll called "Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices" but can't glean much from how I'm to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the answer is yes, it does not trigger the PCNS.  So, you've either to write your own methods using WMI to call the [ChangePassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms697743(v=VS.85).aspx) method of the [CSobject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms697741(v=VS.85).aspx).  The code sample is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms696061(VS.85).aspx).

...or...

The best way to go is to install the Password Management Application.  This installs both a Help Desk utility to let someone search for users in the AD Forest or an End User screen that lets each user change their password.  This application integrates with ILM and sends the correct events to the right places.

[Instructions for installing Password Management on Server 2008.](http://identityunderground.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!69F957860EA2CE40!1615.entry)